# Line following the camera

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js, html5-canvas

How can I make a line that follows a camera view? See the example in the image:

[SEE THE IMAGE EXAMPLE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emVlo.png)

(The red line is the one I want to generate, and the blue dot is the camera.)

I have this code that generates the line, and I also have the mouse movement:

```
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    linewidth: 5
});

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3( 0, 5, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 5, 0, 0 )
);

var LINHATARGET = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
LINHATARGET.position.x = 1;
LINHATARGET.position.y = 0;
LINHATARGET.position.z = 0;
scene.add( LINHATARGET );
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution :

```
scene.add(camera);
camera.add(line);
line.position.z = -1.0; // put the line in front of the camera
```

Adding the line as a children to the camera will make it follow its movement.

Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmacs149/).